# Google search result does not show rich snippets recipe image

Tags: google-search, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets

I have add Recipe rich and using this help page:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/173379?hl=en

Google detects all added data but doesn't show the image on the result page.

What is the problem?

Recipe page: [Recipe page](http://2nafare.com/%D8%B7%D8%B1%D8%B2-%D8%AA%D9%87%DB%8C%D9%87-%D8%AA%D9%87-%DA%86%DB%8C%D9%86-%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%BA-%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%B4%D9%85%D8%B2%D9%87-%D9%88-%D9%BE%D8%B1-%D8%B7%D8%B1%D9%81%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B1/)
Search page: [Search page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D8%AA%D9%87%20%DA%86%DB%8C%D9%86%20%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%BA&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

[image: Image of result page]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested your page (with rich snippet code) in the Google's rich snippet testing tool?

Comment: I would recommend using any third party recipe rich snippet plugin for wordpress. There are a few popular ones like Easy Recipe (https://wordpress.org/plugins/easyrecipe/) and All in One Schema.org Rich Snippets (http://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/a-simple-guide-to-rich-snippets-for-wordpress)

Let me know if you'd like to try any of these and if they work for you.

Thanks,
Moin.